# Array-like immutable (persistent) data structure implementation with fast indexing, append, prepend, iteration

Tags: data-structures, functional-programming, persistent-data-structure

I'm looking for a [persistent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure) data structure similar to array (but immutable), allowing for fast indexing, append, prepend, and iteration (good locality) operations.

Clojure provides persistent Vector, but it's only for fast append. Scala's Vector has effectively constant-time append and prepend, but I can't get how it's implemented, since it's based on same data structure (bit-mapped vector trie) as Clojure vector, and, as I understand, bit-mapped vector trie can't have fast prepend without some tricks.

I'm interested not in ready to use implementation but in a description of how to implement such a data structure myself.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The obvious candidate is a [persistent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure) balanced binary tree.  All the operations you listed can be performed in $O(1)$ or $O(\lg n)$ time, using [path copying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure#Path_Copying).  For more details on how to achieve this runtime, see Chris Okasaki's book referenced below or [my answer here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/18266/755).

Of course, as an variant, each leaf of such a tree could itself contain an immutable array (a sequence of consecutive values).  This makes updating a value less efficient, but it might work well for your situation, if you never intend to modify an existing value, just append and prepend.  In this way, your vector is represented as a sequence of immutable sequences, represented as a balanced binary tree with immutable arrays in the leaves.  This allows for fast indexing (logarithmic in the number of leaves), fast append and prepend, and fast iteration.  The worst-case asymptotic complexity is no better, but the performance in practice might be significantly better.

The standard reference is Chris Okasaki's 1998 book "Purely functional data structures".
See also

- [What classes of data structures can be made persistent?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/18262/755)
- [What's new in purely functional data structures since Okasaki?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/1539/5038)
- [What are the outstanding questions in purely functional data structures?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/1586/5038)
- [Ten Years of Purely Functional Data Structures](http://okasaki.blogspot.com/2008/02/ten-years-of-purely-functional-data.html)

Comment: Thank you. Looks like RRB-trees are good candidate, and they already have (not full) Clojure implementation.

Comment: I guess Okasaki tells us how to attain these runtimes under immutability and persistence?

Comment: @Raphael, yup.  I've added references to explain how you achieve the runtime (to the beginning of my answer).

Answer (score 4):

I have described one implementation of such a data structure in my article about incremental regular expression matching - see http://jkff.info/articles/ire/#ropes-strings-with-fast-concatenation and the text below and above that section.

It's a variety of a constant-height tree (like B-trees or 2-3 trees). Basically it's a (2,3) tree, whose leaves are (N, 2N-1) arrays, in order to avoid per-element overhead.  (A (N, 2N-1) array is an array whose lengths in the range N..2N-1.)  Larger N gives you smaller overhead but linearly increases the complexity of splitting and concatenation. Operations such as indexing, splitting and concatenation are very similar to the way they work in 2-3 trees, generalizing to (N, 2N-1) at the leaf level.

Comment: Links break; please give a proper, robust reference (that allows people to find your paper without the link).

Comment: I didn't publish the paper in any journal, only on my personal website. Should probably put it on Arxiv though, good idea.

Comment: I was mostly thinking about author(s), title and year -- that makes Googling easier if need be. Putting it on arXiv would be even better, true!