# Why are functional programs considered slower than procedural counterparts asymptotically, if the opposite appears true?

Tags: algorithm-analysis, lambda-calculus, efficiency, functional-programming, loops

I've read and been told way too many times that functional algorithms and data structures have an obligatory `O(log(N))` slowdown in respect to their procedural (for-loop/array-based) counterparts. But, after thinking about it, I don't see how that could be true. Mind this `for loop`

```
int arbitrary_sum(int* arr, int size, int n){ 
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) 
         sum += arr[(int)(random()*size)];
    return sum; 
}
```

That sums `N` random elements of an array. You'd saiy this is `O(N)`, but that is taking in account array indexing is `O(1)`, which can't be true. For simplicity, assume memory cells are stored linearly. Since that chip must occupy a linear amount of space, and since a signal requires a linear amount of time to travel given space, then it is obvious an indexing operation takes at least `O(S)` time to complete. That is the time a signal takes to go from the CPU to the memory cell and come back. This means that **the complexity of a for-loop is O(N*S)**, where `N` is the number of interactions and **S is the size of the state that is visible on that `for-loop`.** This way, the textbook `int sum(int* array, int size)` function, for example, can't be `O(N)` - it is, actually, `O(N^2)`, for any reasonable implementation of `for`, as far as physical laws apply. Using layers of caches we are able to shrink the initial `S` factor and amend this effects, but that has a runtime cost and doesn't change the asymptotics. Now, lets look at the functional counterpart. The most obvious way to sum a container of numbers functionally is folding over a list. For simplicity, lets examine the sum of `0` to `4` using church lists:

```
((λc.(λn.(c 0 (c 1 (c 2 (c 3 (c 4 n))))))) + 0)
```

We can optimally evaluate a λ program is using an interaction net, so, lets encode that program as one:

[image: interaction net for the sum of 0 til 4 on the lambda calculus]

Now, let me propose a new model of computer. Instead of separating the CPU and the memory, we instead store a simplistic computing unit together with each memory cell, each one capable of sending/receiving signals and processing local reductions. On this system, we can reduce the `((λ ...list...) +)` abstraction by sending parallel signals from the topmost `λ` node to each corresponding application. We can also reduce the outermost abstraction by sending `0` to the last application of the list. All that takes no more than 2 runs through the list, and the result is:

[image: second interaction]

From here on, it is clear that the rest of the computation will take a linear amount of time to complete. After all, each redex is local, and the redexes are reduced one by one, producing the result from the tail of the list up to its head.

[image: I'm tired of typing]

Under this point of view, it seems to me that functional programs are actually asymptotically faster than imperative counterparts, so, why is the opposite considered the truth?

Comment: Are you sure it's a good idea to compare the complexity of two different languages under two different, non-standard computational models?

Comment: *"I've read and been told way too many times that functional algorithms and data structures have an obligatory O(log(N)) slowdown in respect to their procedural counterparts"* - Where specifically did you read that?  That statement is not correct.  The slowdown is *at most* O(log N), but is often significantly less than that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What classes of data structures can be made persistent?](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/18262/what-classes-of-data-structures-can-be-made-persistent)

Comment: I'm proposing http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/18262/755 as a dup.  The question asks why functional programming is considered to be slower than imperative programming.  It's not necessarily slower -- that's a misconception -- but if this asks for an explanation why functional programming is potentially slower than imperative programming, by at most a O(log n) factor, that is explained at http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/18262/755.  If this doesn't answer the question you had in mind, please edit the question to make it clearer what you are looking for and to address the comments.

Comment: @D.W. You give a good explanation of the $O(\log n)$ alledged slowdown
on that
[question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/18262). Still, this
question seems a bit wider. Persistant data structures may mimic the
constraint that no data is ever overwritten, but nothing says, afaik,
that implementaing a functional program requires necessarily
persistent data structures. And if that were the case, you would have
to do some convincing explaining for it, which you have not. So
considering this question a duplicate is stretching the idea to the
point where any theorem is a duplicate of axioms.

Comment: @babou, thank you for your comments.  The connection is that, in a pure functional language, all data structures must be persistent -- you cannot express a non-persistent data structure in a purely functional language, as overwriting is not possible in a purely functional language.  That question gives an example of a data structure that supports $O(1)$ time operation in an imperative language but for which there is no known way to implement the data structure with the same running time in a purely functional setting.

Comment: @D.W. I am no specialist of functional compilers, but I would guess
that many functional programs can be compiled into some imperative
counterpart. The $O(\log n)$ factor comes from implementing
modifications as a table of differences caching incremental changes.
But when part of the original structure is not to be read again by the
functional program, the compiled code can actually do the
update (a bit like tail recursion elimination). Or did I miss a point? Anyway, my remark was that the two
questions are related, and that is useful information, but calling
them duplicate seems excessive.

Comment: @babou almost gets the point. You can encode many algorithms on the LC without the so called persistent data structures. Of course, any LC structure is persistent, but that name address a specific kind of structure. For example, if you wanted to paint a 10x10 square in a big bitmap, you could use a persistent array and 100 log(N) operations... or you could use a scott list, a zipper and 100 O(1) operations. Zippers+lists give you the same "complexity" as C arrays on that case, and there is no evidence that can't always be done.

Comment: Also, with all due respect, but those questions are so different I'm amazed it was flagged as a dup. They in fact share nothing in common other than being about functional programming and complexity. (I've deleted my last comment since I understand where you made the connection, but the "persistent data structures must have a log(N)" slowdown mentioned on that answer is obvious and has nothing to do with what is asked here, since I'm in no way restricting algorithms to use those structures and the provided example itself doesn't use them at all.)

Answer (score 5):

Without fully answering your question, I would like to answer it at
least partially by remarking that computation cost can be evaluated
only with respect to an abstract model of computation.

If you want to use two different models, for two different programs,
than you have to determine the complexity of reducing each model to
the other, in order to have a meaningful comparison.

Another point is that physics does not well qualify as a computation
model for several reasons:

- it is not clear enough what physics allows and does not allow regarding of computation, computation speed, storage, etc.
- computation models are defined with various assumptions about unit
  operations and their costs, and about infinity and asymptotics,
  which are not meant to be a reflection of reality, but only an
  approximation of reality intended to facilitate the analysis of
  some phenomena, whether abstract or physical.

  This is why Turing machines are more appropriate than finite
  automata theory to analyse the behavior of devices with very large,
  though still finite memory. For example, the powerset construction
  of DFA may exist in theory when the memory is finite, however big,
  but may also quickly exceed the capacity of our limited universe,
  thus hardly making any sense.

Considering your first example about the "physical" time cost of
executing a `for loop` on an array of size $n$. If we are to do
asymptotic physics, we have to do it right, or at least as right as
current knowledge in physics will allow. Due to universe expansion,
the part of the universe that we can ever hope to access is bounded by
a radius of some $z$ zillion light-years (corresponding to a distance
at which the expansion speed relative to us equals the speed of
light), so that nothing relevant to us can be further away.

You can see that as good news: distances being bounded, access is
asymptotically in constant time, so that the classically accepted cost
analysis does hold, despite your remarks.

Of course, since you still want to have arbitrarily large memory, you
have to assume that this finite sphere can hold infinitely many bits
of information ... which I fear physicists cannot really tell. But
let's be optimistic.

Another way to do away with your remark is to consider that the access
time is small enough that it will not really impact the computing
time, unless you have specific reasons to think otherwise.

Some high speed computer do have to be programmed taking into account
physical distances, in particular to memory. But why should functional
program be exempted from such physical limitations. How much
computational capacity do you store with each cell?  Instead of the
$+$ operator, can you pass any arbitrarily complex fuction as
parameter and still have it reduced locally in each memory cell.

Or to put it differently, what prevents an imperative program from
taking advantage of an architecture that has computing power in each
memory cell. This is remindful of various specialized architectures,
such as [vector processors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_processor).