# How would a priority queue be implemented in a functional programming language?

Tags: functional-programming, priority-queues

How would a priority queue be coded efficiently in a functional programming language? I'm new to functional programming, but I'm having difficulty understanding how a data structure that seems to require mutability would be coded in a functional programming language, or how to take advantage of lazy evaluation to pull this off.

Are there any working examples of priority queues being coded in a functional programming language?

Comment: Questions about particular programming languages are off-topic here.

Comment: I'm asking about functional programming languages in general and I removed the reference to Haskell

Comment: Check Chris Okasaki's thesis [Purely Functional Data Structures](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/theses/okasaki.pdf) or his book of the same name. It is, without a doubt, one of the most significant references for this question. He also had [a nice chapter](https://www.macmillanihe.com/resources/sample-chapters/9780333992852_sample.pdf) in [The Fun of Programming](https://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/publications/books/fop/) that provides a very simple implementation of a heap with decent (though not the absolute best) asymptotic performance.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/18262/755